# Attempting to change the path color, but something unexpected happens. Not sure how to make it work as expected?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

Attempting to change the path color, but something unexpected happens. Not sure how to make it work as expected?

Here is a gif of me demonstrating the issue when I attempt to change the color.

[image]

Comment: Look at the icon under color. See it has two different colors. One is fill qnd one stroke. Click on the stroke color you can now set it.

Comment: You're changing the **fill** not the **stroke**.